# Android; OkHttpClient not working with httpS

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Currently I am using my `httpclient` for only `http requests`, but now i want to use `https` aswell.
I changed my `http URL` to a `https URL` and my application won't connect to the url.

fyi: I can connect with my browser to the `https url` and get my response just not within my application itself

any ideas what the issue could be or what im doing wrong?

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https:xyz.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
```

Comment: could you add the error android studio gives you please?

Comment: why you do not use it from Retrofit2 ??

Comment: `https:xyz.com/api/` is not syntactically valid - is that really the syntax you have in your code? Missing slashes after `https:`.

Comment: @JavadDehban i am using retrofit2 2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to perform HTTPS connections, an SSL certificate and transport configuration must be present, or your device won't know how to encrypt and more importantly *trust* the other end.

In short, take a look at the [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) official documentation to understand this and what it entails.

If all you care for now is *debugging*, then you can also find the information on how to "bypass" this for Debugging builds in the [same page](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingDebugCa).

In short (and I quote):

> When debugging an app that connects over HTTPS, you may want to connect to a local development server, which does not have the SSL certificate for your production server.

1. Add a file in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` (create it)
2. Paste something like this (but **read what it means and understand it, the security of your app and your user's information is at risk if you don't learn this stuff**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```